# Displaying an array of images with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to display an array of images using JavaScript, but he doesn't seem to find the images. I do get however this messages on screen: [Object HTMLImage Element]

Any help would be appreciated. I'm a student trying to learn.

```js
let slideshow;
let currentItem = 0;
let items = [6];
//let ready = true;
items[0] = new Image();
items[0].src = "../images/bier%20tafe.jpeg";

items[1] = new Image();
items[1].src = '../images/pintjes.jpeg';

items[2] = new Image();
items[2].src = '../images/flesjes.jpeg';

items[3] = new Image();
items[3].src = '../images/grain.jpg';

items[4] = new Image();
items[4].src = '../images/cigar.jpg';

items[5] = new Image();
items[5].src = '../images/whiskey.jpg';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(ev){
  slideshow = document.querySelector('.slideshow');
  slideshow.addEventListener('click', next);
  //call the event once to start the show
  slideshow.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));
  //next(); //the line above is the same as calling next()
});

function next(ev){
  //this runs when the slideshow has been clicked
  ev.preventDefault();
  //call the function to remove the oldest item (if it exists)
  removeItem();
  //add the new one
  let item = document.createElement('div');
  item.textContent = items[currentItem];
  item.classList.add("slideshow-item");
  slideshow.appendChild(item);
  setTimeout(function(){
    item.classList.add('active');
    //this could fail if the user clicked twice within 20 milliseconds
  }, 20);
  currentItem++;
  if(currentItem > items.length-1){
    currentItem = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Just an FYI - `let items = [6];` is not making a new array with the size of 6, but creating a new array and setting `6` at index `0`

Comment: Maybe this: 
 item.textContent = items[currentItem];
You should be probably creating elements of type img, not div.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me your mistake is in using:

> item.textContent = items[currentItem];

This is trying to set a text element, and since you're giving it an image object, it's just giving you the textContent value of that object "[Object HTMLImage Element]".

Instead you need to actually place the image inside your div:

> **item.appendChild(** items[currentItem] **)**;

This will append the image as a child into the div you specified.

Comment: Glad I could help. If you feel like the answer is adequate, please accept it as the answer to help anyone who finds your question in the future.